# Customize spring-boot jaeger auto-configuration

Tags: spring-boot, jaeger, opentracing

I'm working on a POC and was able to integrate 2 microservices with JaegerUI.

Request to an endpoint in serviceA calls an endpoint in serviceB and returns a response.

I have used below dependencies:

spring.boot.version : 2.1.4.RELEASE

```
<groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>

 <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
        <artifactId>opentracing-spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
```

Spring autoconfiguration takes care of everything so just added the required properties:

```
opentracing.jaeger.http-sender.url

opentracing.jaeger.service-name

opentracing.jaeger.enabled

opentracing.spring.cloud.async.enabled
```

I want to achieve the below:

1. I want to add application logs to the span so that they are visible in JaegerUI.
2. I want to add some fields to span tags so that it's easy to search in JaegerUI.
3. Also, I want the spanId and traceId to the application log.
4. Is it possible to search in JaegerUI based on spanId/traceId? If yes, how?

Based on the answer in below SO question:

[How to enrich Jaeger opentracing data with the application logs (produced by slf4j) for Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50855480/how-to-enrich-jaeger-opentracing-data-with-the-application-logs-produced-by-slf)

opentracing-spring-cloud-starter dependency should automatically take care of sending app logs to span in JaegerUI.

I have a log statement like below in serviceA:

logger.info("sending request to serviceB.");

But above log is not getting captured in corresponding span and not visible in JaegerUI.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the above scenarios are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was studying Opentracing and Jeager and I've used this tutorial to get familiar with the basic possibilities:
https://github.com/yurishkuro/opentracing-tutorial/tree/master/java

If you take a look in the case 1 (Hello World), it explains how to "[Annotate the Trace with Tags and Logs](https://github.com/yurishkuro/opentracing-tutorial/tree/master/java/src/main/java/lesson01#annotate-the-trace-with-tags-and-logs)".
That would answer your questions 1, 2 and 3, as with that you can add all the info that you would like within spans and logs.

Here is a snippet from the repository (but I'd recommend checking there, as it has a more detailed explanation):

```
Span span = tracer.buildSpan("say-hello").start();
span.setTag("hello-to", helloTo);
```

In this case `helloTo` is a variable containing a name, to whom the app will say hello. It would create a span tag called hello-to with the value that is coming from the execution.

Below we have an example for the logs case, where the whole `helloStr` message is added to the logs:

```
// this goes inside the sayHello method
String helloStr = String.format("Hello, %s!", helloTo);
span.log(ImmutableMap.of("event", "string-format", "value", helloStr));

System.out.println(helloStr);
span.log(ImmutableMap.of("event", "println"));
```

Regarding the last question, that would be easier, you can use the Jaeger UI to search for the trace you would like, there is a field for that on the top left corner:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your answer is relevant. However, I wanted to use the auto configured tracer instance provided by the Spring-Boot. I have figured it out. Basically, we can inject the Spring provided tracer and use it for accessing the active spans. I will be adding an answer of my own.

Answer (score 1):

There you go.

1. I want to add application logs to the span so that they are visible in JaegerUI.

```
Span span = tracer.buildSpan("my-span-name").start();
span.setTag("my-tag-name", "my-tag-value");
```

There are various overloaded methods as follows

```
Span setTag(String key, String value);
Span setTag(String key, boolean value);
Span setTag(String key, Number value);
```

2. I want to add some fields to span tags so that it's easy to search in JaegerUI.

   Jaeger API provides **log** method to log multiple fields that needs to be added to a map, the method signature is as follows,

`Span log(Map<String, ?> fields);`

eg:

```
span.log(
   ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object>()
     .put("event", "soft error")
     .put("type", "cache timeout")
     .put("waited.millis", 1500)
     .build()
);
```

3. Also, I want the spanId and traceId to the application log.

spanId and traceId are stored in JaegerSpanContext class, which can be obtained from context() method of Span class.

```
    JaegerSpanContext spanContext = (JaegerSpanContext)sprintSpan.context();
    long spanId = spanContext.getSpanId();
    long traceId = spanContext.getTraceId();
```

4. Is it possible to search in JaegerUI based on spanId/traceId? If yes, how?

There is a search box in the navigation bar of Jaeger UI where you can search traces by trace ID.

[image]