# Auto instrumentation for nodejs application to send logs to jaeger

Tags: javascript, node.js, jaeger, opentracing

I have a simple node application like this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const tracer = require(INIT_TRACER_CODE);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  const span = tracer.startSpan("demo");
  span.log({
    event: 'logging',
    value: 'App started on port'
  });
  span.finish();
})
```

I have configured the tracer with jaeger and able to send the traces and logs to jaeger with the above code. Now the question is how can i send the application logs automatically to jaeger instance without doing instrumentation. I have read that it is possible in spring boot. Refer this stackoverflow discussion ([How to enrich Jaeger opentracing data with the application logs (produced by slf4j) for Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50855480/how-to-enrich-jaeger-opentracing-data-with-the-application-logs-produced-by-slf)). Do we have this equivalent in nodejs ?